# CMake: How to include only one header directory

Tags: cmake, header, include

It seems the CMake **include_directories** will add not only the passed directory but also all its sub directories to the include list.
Is there a way to add only one directory (without its sub directories), i.e. some sort on **include_directory** command?

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html), only the folders indicated int he command are added, not the subfolders. Of course, if you have a subfolder `foo` and someone does `#include <foo/bar.h`, then the file will be included.

Consider using `target_include_directories` as it is more flexible and better, as it targets one target, and if the target is reused, then dependent includes may also be carried to the dependent targets (depending on `PUBLIC`/`PRIVATE`/`INTERFACE`).